# Where do I create google-managed SSL certificate for kubernetes cluster deployment?

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to set up SSL on my site. I deployed to an autopilot kubernetes cluster. I have a domain through Google Domains which has DNS pointing to my kubernetes exposed ip with an A record. I've found at least two different places in GCP so far that seem to guide me through creating a Google-managed SSL cert, but neither of them is working. One is through app engine, I don't believe that's what I need to use. The other is through Network Services -> Load balancing. I'm starting to think that is also not what I should be using. Where do I go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One is through app engine, I don't believe that's what I need to use.

You're right, it's definitely the wrong direction. As you don't use the **App Engine** but **Kubernetes Engine** it's not the part of the docs you're interested in.

You should start with [this article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs) in the official **GCP Docs** and the missing piece of the puzzle is an **Ingress resource**, you need to create to expose your app externally. As you can see it's part of **Google Kubernetes Engine** docs:

> Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) > Documentation > Guides

As you can read in the above mentioned article:

> Note: This feature is only available with Ingress for External HTTP(S)
> Load Balancing.

about which you can read more in [this section](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress).

As everything is nicely described in the docs, I only emphasize here the key points.

First, check your **GKE** version and make sure you use the correct [API version](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#api_versions) to create `ManagedCertificate` custom resource:

> You configure Google-managed SSL certificates using a
> `ManagedCertificate` custom resource, which is available in different
> API versions, depending on your GKE cluster version:
>
> - ManagedCertificate v1beta2 API is available in GKE cluster versions 1.15 and later.
> - ManagedCertificate v1 API is available in GKE cluster versions 1.17.9-gke.6300 and later.
>
> Although GKE clusters currently support ManagedCertificate v1beta1
> API, this API version is deprecated and will be removed in future GKE
> versions. It's recommended that you use a newer API version.

In essence, [creating an Ingress with a Google-managed certificate](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#creating_an_ingress_with_a_google-managed_certificate) comes down to these two basic steps:

> - Create a ManagedCertificate object.
> - Associate the ManagedCertificate object to an Ingress by adding an annotation networking.gke.io/managed-certificates to the Ingress. This
>   annotation is a comma-separated list of ManagedCertificate resources,
>   cert1,cert2,cert3 for example.

which is described in detail [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#setting_up_a_google-managed_certificate).

Also pay special attention to [prerequisites](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#prerequisites):

> - You must own the domain name. The domain name must be no longer than 63 characters. You can use  [Google
>   Domains](https://domains.google.com/)  or another registrar.

This one you've already met.

> - Your  `"kubernetes.io/ingress.class"`  must be  `"gce"`.
> - Create a  [reserved (static) external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address).
>   Reserving a static IP address guarantees that it remains yours, even
>   if you delete the Ingress. If you do not reserve an address, it may
>   change requiring you to reconfigure your domain's DNS records. Use
>   `gcloud`  command-line tool or the Cloud Console to create a reserved
>   IP address.

The last one is particularly important, if you don't want to reconfigure your domain at a later point in time.